# Python - Get value from field in Sql Server Statement

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a table animal in a SQLSERVER database with two fields: id and name.

I'm trying to do this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=TEST;UID=sa;PWD=123456'
)

id = 1

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT id, name FROM animal WHERE id=?', (id,))

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row.name
```

But for some reason it gives me the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Can anyone help me to get the value from the field and save it in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print row.name` use `print row[1]`. The `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples in the form `[(1234, 'Alice Cooper'), ...]`